# ASP.NET - Async - A system that syncs between two other systems

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I am trying to create a system that synchronizes between two other systems' data.

I work on ASP.NET Web Forms using VB (Cannot be changed)

The main system functions will be in a form of Web API which will be triggered by a scheduled task or other events, such as a website form or a landing page.

Each of these functions call a REST API of System 1 and the REST API of System 2 , operates the data, and then calls each system REST APIs to update both sides.

I chose to use a ASP.NET Web Api 2 for the main system, and HttpClient to call the functions.

There will be hundreds of thousands of transactions per day. It is a lot! So I chose to use async/await methods for the HttpClient, (because of the many simultaneous long processing requests), but ASP.NET seems to have forced me to convert all the functions from bottom to top, including the Web Api functions and the database access **to Async**!

So I ended up changing all the functions to Async and in all the functions that call them I use Await for everything.

Everything seems to work. I don't know if what I did is correct, and I see there is no way to check if my functions are actually working asynchronically.

About the `ConfigureAwait(False)` I added it because I don't have operations that are context related. If there will be I will remove this statement. I read it is recommended to use it when it is possible. (Am I right?)

***SMALL COMMENT*:**
Why is my solution good??? I am trying to avoid blocking the main thread by creating much more worker threads. Why is this a better solution? I am creating a lot of awaits which each one starts a worker. Isn't it a worse practice than the synchronic solution????

**Can somebody tell me if what I am doing is correct and if not - please explain why or if there are other approaches to this scenario?**

Here is the code for example (only the relevant parts). A little explanation of what you see:

- The WebApi Controller has an Login function
- The Login function calls the System1.DoSomething asynchronically
- The System1.DoSomething calls the private function
  System1.SetCredentials asynchronically
- The System1.DoSomething also uses HttpHandler to get data
  asynchronically from System1's API
- System1.SetCredentials function calls MyLoginManager.GetCredentials asynchronically
- MyLoginManager.GetCredentials calls the database asynchronically using DBHelper.ExecuteReaderAsync
- The DBHelper.ExecuteReaderAsync function calls ExecuteReaderAsync
  asynchronically and also opens the connection asynchronically using
  OpenAsync() function

**The WebAPI Controller**

```
     Public Class WebApiController
   Inherits ApiController
     Public Async Function Login() As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of IHttpActionResult)
        Dim result As MyResult= Await System1.DoSomething().ConfigureAwait(False)
     End Function
```

**The System1 Class**

```
 Public Class System1
    Public Shared Async Function DoSomething() As Task(Of MyResult)
        Try
            Using client As New HttpClient
                client.BaseAddress = New Uri("blablabla")
                Await SetCredentials(client).ConfigureAwait(False)
                Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.GetAsync(urlParameters).ConfigureAwait(False)

                ... More code
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Function

 Private Shared Async Function SetCredentials(client As HttpClient) As Task
            Dim auth As BasicAuthenticationData = Await MyLoginManager.GetCredentials.ConfigureAwait(False)
            Dim credentials As String = Cryptography.EncodeBase64(String.Format("{0}\{1}:{2}", auth.userName, auth.userPassword))
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " & credentials)

            ... More code
        End Function
    End Class
```

**The MyLoginManager Class**

```
  Public Class MyLoginManager
  Public Shared Async Function GetCredentials() As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of BasicAuthenticationData)
            Dim auth As New BasicAuthenticationData

            Dim dbConn As String = DBConnection.GetConnection(True)
            Dim q As String = "SELECT * FROM BlaBlaBla"

            Using sdr As SqlDataReader = Await DBHelper.ExecuteReaderAsync(dbConn, q, Nothing).ConfigureAwait(False)
                 ... More code
            End Using

            Return auth
        End Function
End Class
```

**The DBHelper Class**

```
Public Class DBHelper
    Public Shared Async Function ExecuteReaderAsync(ByVal dbConnection As String, ByVal commandText As String, ByVal params() As SqlParameter) As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of SqlDataReader)
            Dim dbConnectionAsync As String = New SqlConnectionStringBuilder(dbConnection) With {
                .AsynchronousProcessing = True
            }.ToString

            Dim objConn As New SqlConnection(dbConnectionAsync)

            Dim oc As New SqlCommand(commandText, objConn)
            Dim sdr As SqlDataReader

            ' Throws a custom exception if there is a problem
            Try

                Await oc.Connection.OpenAsync.ConfigureAwait(False)
                sdr = Await oc.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection).ConfigureAwait(False)

                Return sdr
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a call to `ConfigureAwait(false)` to any await behind any await that comes out of any controller action.

As [Mister Epic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/980799/mister-epic) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44782605/asp-net-async-a-system-that-syncs-between-two-other-systems/44782909#44782909) you'll loose things like `HttpContext.Current` if you call `ConfigureAwait(false)` and you shouldn't do that on controller action methods. But that also means that every time you don't you incur in context switching.

What you should do is extract the logic in controller action methods to their own methods (preferably on their own class) and pass every thing they need to do their work.

So, the only thing you did wrong was to call `ConfigureAwait(false)` in the controller action method.

Comment: You mean the WebApi controller right? There is a function inside that goes to the System1 class so as you said I do not have logic inside the controller. I have a call to the logic of System1 in a separate class. So according to what you both said (@paulo morgado and @mister epic)  the only ConfigureAwait(false) statement i must remove is the one inaide the WebApi controller. Is this correct?

Comment: And i didn't inderstand when will i incur in context switching. Context switching happens when you DO include the ConfigureWait(false) statement. If  i DON'T add it the context remains the same as before

Comment: Context switching happens when there's a `SynchronizationContext`, like in ASP.NET (not core), WinForms, WPF, UWP, etc. If `ConfigureAwait(false)` is not used, instead of the continuation running where it landed, it will be posted to the `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: I got lost in these explanations. What should I do for this specific example? Where would I want to use the landed context and when the 'SynchronizationContext'?

Comment: Also, why is my solution good??? I am trying to avoid blocking the main thread by creating much more worker threads. Why is this a better solution? I am creating a lot of awaits which each one starts a worker. Isn't it a worse practice than the synchronic solution????

Comment: @AsafEpelbaum You don't create a worder with each await - await *yields the thread back to the threadpool* (usually...). That's useful for I/O operations where your application is waiting for a signal that the operation has completed. While your app waits, you can either have your thread wait uselessly, or you can yield it back to the thread pool where it could be dispatched to do some useful work.

Comment: But when you send an async task to execute, then the thread pool is freed from this task until it yields back when it is finished, right?
But the async task is still executed somewhere by some other type of worker. If I create too many async tasks I end up creating a lot of that type of workers and I must assume they also cost some expensive memory while they are executing. **So isn't sending async tasks and awaiting them for each function and their nested functions as well - A worse solution than the synchronized solution????**

Comment: @AsafEpelbaum, have a look at Steve's blog: https://blog.stephencleary.com/

Comment: @Paulo - Can you point me to a specific topic in the blog? I read some posts but I can't find what I am looking for. And most of his posts are from a few years back and I know the technology changed and there were new methods and architectures, so I don't know how relevant is to read 'outdated' information.

Comment: @AsafEpelbaum, everything on that blog related to async-await is up to date and you seem the really need to read it all. It's up to you if you read it or not.

Comment: I went over the blog and I read the relevant information for me. Thank you all very much for your help. I will accept this answer because it addresses exactly the issues in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't add `ConfigureAwait` in your web api project. Use it in library code.

The big gotcha is that when you call a method that uses `ConfigureAwait`, you'll lose your context. Your context includes important details like your session, so you'll need to ensure you capture any details from `HttpContext` you need before you call into library code that uses `ConfigureAwait`.

Comment: I don't quite understand what do you mean by "library code". What is a lobrary code? You suggest to remove the configure false. I can do that in places i need the context, but if i dont manage a session nor need the context i can add it safely. Am i right?

Comment: And on other subject. Is the code correct? Is this how async code hierarchy should be written? This code can manage thousands of requests simultaneously without blocking the main thread? Isnt there a risk by creating too many worker threads? I really am confused. I wanted to asynchify the httpclient parts but the Asp.net almost forced me to convert all my code to async. I don't know right from wrong at this point.